# Rice distribution in 3D spce

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to calculate:
$$\text{Var}\left(\sqrt {(x - a)^2 + (y -b)^2) + (y-c)^2}\right)$$
Where $X,Y,Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,k^2)$ where $k^2$ is known, and $a,b,c$ are know constants.

In the case of 2 variables, it seems like [Rice Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution) can be used to get to a solution.

1. Is there an analogue of the Rice Distribution in 3D space?? If there is, can someone supply information on this (especially regarding on calculating the mean and variance).
2. If there isn't some analogue, how else can this problem be approached?

Comment: [This question may be useful](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167133/expected-magnitude-of-a-vector-from-a-multivariate-normal)

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution

First of all assume $X, Y, Z$ are i.i.d. as $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, then

$$ W = \frac {1} {\sigma^2}\left[(X - a)^2 + (Y - b)^2 + (Z - c)^2\right]$$

follows a Non-Central Chi Square distribution with degrees of freedom $k = 3$ and non-centrality parameter $\lambda = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$

From the pdf definition, we know that
$$ E[W^n] = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda/2} \frac {(\lambda/2)^i} {i!}E[Y_{k+2i}^n]$$
where $Y_{k+2i} \sim \chi^2(k+2i)$. When $n = 1$, we obtain the mean

$$ E[W] 
= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda/2} \frac {(\lambda/2)^i} {i!}E[Y_{k+2i}] 
= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda/2} \frac {(\lambda/2)^i} {i!}(k+2i)
= k + 2(\lambda/2) = k + \lambda$$

The square root is more troublesome. Note
$$ E[Y_{k+2i}^{1/2}] = \sqrt{2}\frac {\Gamma((k+2i+1)/2)} {\Gamma((k+2i)/2)}$$

For $k$ is odd, 
$$ \sqrt{2}\frac {\Gamma((k+2i+1)/2)} {\Gamma((k+2i)/2)} 
= \frac {[((k - 1)/2 + i)!]^2} {(k-1+2i)!}2^{k-1/2+2i}$$

and so $E[\sqrt{W}]$ may not be simplified from the series form.

Putting everything together,

$$ Var[\sigma\sqrt{W}] = \sigma^2(E[W] - E[\sqrt{W}]^2) 
= \sigma^2(k + \lambda - E[\sqrt{W}]^2)$$

where
$$ E[\sqrt{W}] = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda/2} \frac {(\lambda/2)^i} {i!}
\frac {[((k - 1)/2 + i)!]^2} {(k-1+2i)!}2^{k-1/2+2i}$$