# What is the expected value of this combination of three independent variables?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Suppose you have three independent random variables $x$, $y$, and $z$ that are distributed as follows:

$x$ ~ $N(0,\sigma_x)$, 
$y$ ~ $N(0,\sigma_y)$, and
$z$ ~ $N(z_{average},\sigma_z)$.

I am trying to find the expected value and variance of the quantity $P=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 +z^2}$. Since $\sigma_P^2 = E(P^2)-E(P)^2$, and $E(P^2)=\sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2+\sigma_z^2+z_{average}^2$, I only need the expected value of this quantity. I have looked at some related questions and see that it should be of the form
$$\iiint \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\frac{1}{\sigma_x\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma_x^2}\frac{1}{\sigma_y\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-y^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\frac{1}{\sigma_z\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-(z-z_{average})^2}{2\sigma_z^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
But I have no idea how to evaluate this integral. I understand that with two dimensions elliptical integration can be used, but what kind of method is there to evaluate this triple integral?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's $z_{\mathrm{average}}$?

Comment: $z_{average}$ represents the mean of random variable z. Its some non-zero number.

Comment: Check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988664/rice-distribution-in-3d-spce) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167133/expected-magnitude-of-a-vector-from-a-multivariate-normal).

Comment: But how would the answer be changed if the means were non-zero or if the variances differed?

Comment: Yes, it's tough. Btw you need to use "@" or I wont see your comment. Here are some more links: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656762/distribution-of-the-sum-of-squared-independent-normal-random-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89779/sum-of-squares-of-normal-distributions), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67533/sum-of-noncentral-chi-square-random-variables?rq=1).